# Protractor to get value of textarea with line number

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, protractor

I am using Protractor to test my Bootstrap AngularJS application.
The textarea "input" and "output" are have line number associated to it.
So, when I check the value of "output" textarea using `element(by.id('output')).getText()` it always `returns line number'1'` instead of value inside the textarea. Below is the snippet of the html and spec.js file

homepage.html

```
<div>
    <textarea id= "input" ui-codemirror="{ onLoad : editorLoaded }"
                        ng-model="input" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
    <textarea id="output" ui-codemirror="viewerOptions"
                    ng-model="output"></textarea>
</div>
```

homepage.spec.js

```
describe('homepage', function() {

  it('check if output matches input', function() {
        browser.get('your url');
        var input = element(by.model('input'));
        input.sendKeys('abc;');
        var result = element(by.id('output'));
        expect(result.getText()).toEqual('abc;');
    });

});
```

Any pointer on how to solve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem** : Not able to fetch the value from TexArea. After debugging the problem, I found the root cause to be sendKey() api. I used the below snippet to write text to TextArea, but the browser always showed empty field.

```
var input = element(by.model('input'));
input.sendKeys('abc;');
```

**Solution** : After alot of trial and error found that `browser.actions().sendKeys('abc;').perform();` helps to enter the text into the TextArea. The perform() api creates a new action sequence using the current driver.

```
describe('Testing UI', function() {

    it('opens a workshop page', function() {
        browser.get('url');
        browser.sleep(2000); 
    });

    it('starts editing', function() {
        var inputField = element(by.id('input'));
        browser.actions().doubleClick(inputField).perform();
    });

    it('enters some text', function() {

        var inputField = element(by.id('input'));
        browser.actions().sendKeys('abc;').perform();

        browser.sleep(3000); // to let you see the result

        var inputcharcount = inputField.getAttribute('value').length;
        expect(inputcharcount,4);

        var result = element(by.id('output'));
        expect(result.getText()).toEqual('abc;');
    });
});
```

I used element(by.id('output')).getText() api to fetch the values from the output textarea. So the complete testcase to enter the text in input textarea (sendKey) and process the output in resulting textarea (getText) worked.

Answer (score 6):

For `input` and `textarea` elements, you should always use `getAttribute('value')` instead of `getText()`. Here's how to use it -

```
var result = element(by.id('output'));
expect(result.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('abc;');
```

For more information as to why getText doesnt work on input elements please check the protractor faq:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#the-result-of-gettext-from-an-input-element-is-always-empty

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I am still getting testcase failure saying : `"Expected null to equal 'abc;'."` which means `result.getAttribute('value')`is null. Is there something I need to change in my html file???

Comment: @ShwethaV are you sure that your `output` element has data in it? `null` value probably indicates that there is no data in it.

Comment: Modified testcase with below code :-                                             
    `input.click();
     input.sendKeys('abc;');
     browser.driver.sleep(1);
     browser.waitForAngular();
     expect(element(by.id('output')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual('abc;');`                                                                                                        The `input` is processed by servlet to get the `output`, so I introduced a delay, assuming servlet processing is taking time. However it still fails. This use case works perfectly in normal mode.Any pointers??

Comment: Added `browser.sleep(5000);` to see if the input text is visible in UI and turns out sendKey('value'); is not updating the textArea at all. Any idea on how to fix the sendKey issue??? I also, tried to add input.clear(); and got error `element must be user-editable in order to clear it`. Any pointer??